# Problems with Date() in JavaScript - it adds one month?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a strange problem with `Date()` in JavaScript.

I have the following simple code:

```
var date = new Date(2013, 11, 01, 00, 00, 0, 0);
alert(date);
```

That should set the Date to `01 November 2013 00:00:00:00` But instead it sets it to December?
As you can see in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/CBqK2/

What is wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JavaScript months are 0 based, just to confuse you.

From MDN for the `Date` constructor:

> *month* Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

So for your example:

```
var date = new Date(2013, 10, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0);
alert(date);
```

You can read more about `Date` on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: That's a little bit crazy, start the months from zero, when people use 1-12 normal, but thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Set the second value to 10. Date class begins with a 0 for January like in an Array ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Date() returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.

eg:January is 0, February is 1, and so on.

if you want to start from `0` onwards use below format

```
var date = new Date('2013/10/01');
```

Comment: Any particular reason you decided to post the 3rd duplicate answer here?

Comment: when i was typing nothing was there

Comment: That's fine. Legitimate.. but then - you don't have to leave your answer.

Answer (score 0):

the Date has the list of months weekdays starting from zero.

for months it is 0-11 for Jan to Dec and for Week days it is 0-6 for Sun - Sat.

when you say.

var date  = new Date('1381751517000') // I have used the timestamp in milliseconds for 2013-10-14T11:51:00 as js accepts timestamp in milliseconds.

now if we say

day = date.getDay();

it return 1, i.e Monday,

month = date.getMonth()

it returns 9 i.e October.

in the same way when we create the date using the format ('YYYY,MM,DD,HH,mm,ss,ms') we should give the input also in the same way.